# Why is my linear regression not performing good?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, correlation

I created a linear regression model to predict `Power Generation` based on `Temperature` and `Solar Irradiance` values. The values of correlation between the variables are shown below:

```
Power Generation    1.000000
Solar Irradiance    0.437181
Temperature         0.571839
TimestampDay       -0.239430
```

And here are the scatter plots:
[image: scatter plots]

The results however are really bad. [image: results] The R² score for the prediction is `-0.339`, it's not even picking up the trend correctly. I find this odd since the variables have fairly good correlation values. Could it be that it is simply not enough? Could the seasonal effect of my data have anything to do with the bad performance for linear regression?

Here's the full code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import metrics
from osisoft.pidevclub.piwebapi.pi_web_api_client import PIWebApiClient
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

client = PIWebApiClient("https://localhost/piwebapi", useKerberos=False, username="svc_tcc", password="9Dw#7gbb", verifySsl=False)

plantaID = 1

if plantaID == 1: planta = "Karnak"
elif plantaID == 2: planta = "Piney Woods"
elif plantaID == 3: planta = "Bryce Canyon"

path1 = "pi:\EC2AMAZ-8VHQOQJ\\" + planta + ".Total Power Generation Actual"
path2 = "pi:\EC2AMAZ-8VHQOQJ\\" + planta + ".Solar Irradiance Actual"
path3 = "pi:\EC2AMAZ-8VHQOQJ\\" + planta + ".Temperature Actual"

df1 = client.data.get_recorded_values(path=path1,
                                     start_time='1-24mo',
                                     end_time='1',
                                     max_count=100000)
df2 = client.data.get_recorded_values(path=path2,
                                     start_time='1-24mo',
                                     end_time='1',
                                     max_count=100000)
df3 = client.data.get_recorded_values(path=path3,
                                     start_time='1-24mo',
                                     end_time='1',
                                     max_count=100000)

data = [df1.Value, df2.Value, df3.Value, df1.Timestamp]
headers = ["Power Generation", "Solar Irradiance", "Temperature", "Timestamp"]
df = pd.concat(data, axis=1, keys=headers)
df["Timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Timestamp"])
register_matplotlib_converters()
df['TimestampDay'] = (df['Timestamp'] - df['Timestamp'].min())  / np.timedelta64(1,'D')

df_new = df.query('`Solar Irradiance` != 0')

pct_train = 0.9

y = df_new['Power Generation']
X_multiplo = df_new[['Solar Irradiance','Temperature']]

size_train = int(len(y)*pct_train)

X_train_m, X_test_m, y_train_m, y_test_m = train_test_split(X_multiplo, y, test_size=(1-pct_train), shuffle=False)

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_train_m, y_train_m)

print('R² = {}'.format(model.score(X_train_m, y_train_m).round(3))) # Train adjustment

y_treino_previsto_m = model.predict(X_train_m)
y_teste_previsto_m = model.predict(X_test_m)

print('R² = %s' % metrics.r2_score(y_test_m, y_teste_previsto_m).round(3)) # Prediction score
```

Comment: You need to show us your code.  I'm not sure how you are doing LINEAR regression with two independent variables.  Shouldn't you have shown us power vs solar irradiance or power vs temperature instead of power vs time?  That would tell whether linear was the right way to go.

Comment: @TimRoberts sorry I did forget to add the scatter plots. Just added them with an edit.

Comment: What about the code? C:

Comment: This was not your question, but I would discourage linear regression for this problem.

Comment: @DMeneses just added full code! :)

Comment: @anon01 could you please explain why?

Comment: It's kinda difficult to see with the overplotting (make points smaller and/or use alpha). It's hard to say if seasonality is a factor because you don't show the predictors over time, so we don't know if they reflect the daily(?) and annual periodicities seen in the response over time plot. The prediction does not appear to capture the daily variation. The temperature seems to need higher order term(s). I think the recommendation against a LM assumes the timestamp is a predictor, which your code shows is not the case; were it, then perhaps consider a Gaussian Process model.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to run more experiments

1. Try running random forest regressor and see if performance changes
2. Would also advise to change your `train size` to `0.7 or 0.8` and see performance
3. R^2 is not the only evaluation technique, you can try MSE and MAPE

Depending on what your target variable is achieving as a goal, MAPE (mean absolute percentage error) could be better evaluation technique.
If you want to represent time, then consider building time-series model

```
regr = RandomForestRegressor(max_depth=10, random_state=0)
regr.fit(X, y)
```

MAPE

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_absolute_percentage_error.html

RMSE

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error.html